# How to star an angle in RPN?

Tags: pstricks

How can I use `\rput{*<angle>}(...){...}` where `<angle>` is represented in RPN?

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}



\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
    \rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*45}(0,0){$x$}}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
    %\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*! 1 1 atan}(0,0){$x$}} %does not compile!
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

RPN is also called as postfix notation.

```
1 2 add
```

is the representation of `1+2` in infix notation.

The `*` in front of an angle represents an absolute angle that cannot be rotated by other putting containers. In the example above, `\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*45}(0,0){$x$}}` makes the `$x$` gets rotated 45 degrees counter-clockwise and the effect of the outer `\rput` is cancelled.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.  - Could you please explain "RPN"?

Comment: @Bobyandbob RPN = "Reverse Polish Notation", a term coined when ethnic slurs were not politically incorrect, and referring to the stack-based input style of Hewlett-Packard calculators.

Comment: I just gave an answer, but could you tell me what the `*` does?  Depending on your reply, I might be able to improve my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see a problem with `*!`?:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\rput{! 50 40 add}(1,1){\rput{*90}(2,0){*90}}
\rput{! 50 40 add}(1,1){\rput{90}(1,0){90}}
\rput{! 50 40 add}(1,1){\rput{*!90 45 sub}(0,0){45}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*75}(0,-.5){$z$}} 
\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*! 50 25 add}(0,0){!$Z$}} 
\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*45}(1,-.5){$w$}} 
\rput{90}(1,1){\rput{*! 1 1 atan}(1,0){!$W$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]